# How can i pass data from template in Django to Javascript in this specific case

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am using Google map api and i am trying to pass the data (longitude and latitude) to the template then use the data in the javascript  to show a specific location.

location.html

```
{% for venue in property_listing %}
      {{ venue.address }}</br>
      <div id="long">{{ venue.longitude }}</br>
      <div id="lat">{{ venue.latitude }}</br>
{% endfor %}
```

javascript of the same page

```
<script>
      var latitude = REPLACE HERE;
      var longitude = REPLACE HERE;
      // Initialize and add the map
      function initMap() {
      // The location of Uluru
      var uluru = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};
      // The map, centered at Uluru
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 15, center: uluru});
      // The marker, positioned at Uluru
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
    }


    </script>
```

I am tried to replace the value literally but it wont work. What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Wouldn't `var latitude = document.getElementById('lat');` work?

Comment: @LearningNoob I tried it. It did not work.

Comment: Just make sure your javascript is actually below your dom elements.

Comment: the javascript is at the bottom of the page

Comment: Do you take `lat`, `lng` value from `property_listing`? As it a list, it return multiple `lat`, `lng` value.

Comment: @shafik can you elaborate with codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are assigning your data into a **div**. Which doesn't have a proper value attribute. Here is a work around by using `getAttribute()` method.

Assign an attribute named **'value'** and it's corresponding data:

location.html

```
{% for venue in property_listing %}
      {{ venue.address }}</br>
      <div id="long" value="{{ venue.longitude }}">{{ venue.longitude }}</br>
      <div id="lat" value="{{ venue.latitude }}">{{ venue.latitude }}</br>
{% endfor %}
```

In your javascript function, access the data by getting the attribute of your div ids named **value**:

```
<script>
      var latitude = document.getElementById('lat').getAttribute("value");
      var longitude = document.getElementById('long').getAttribute("value");
      // Initialize and add the map
      function initMap() {
      // The location of Uluru
      var uluru = {lat: parseFloat(latitude), lng: parseFloat(longitude)};
      // The map, centered at Uluru
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 15, center: uluru});
      // The marker, positioned at Uluru
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your solution is the one working. the only thing i had to add is ''parseFloat' after the line // The location of Uluru

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<script>
      var latitude = {{ venue.latitude }};
      var longitude = {{ venue.longitude }};
      // Initialize and add the map
      function initMap() {
      // The location of Uluru
      var uluru = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};
      // The map, centered at Uluru
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 15, center: uluru});
      // The marker, positioned at Uluru
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
    }


    </script>
```

Comment: {{ }} "Double curly braces" from django template cannot be used in javascript apparently.

Comment: @CurtisBanks why?  Did you get an error?  This has always worked for me.

Comment: The `{{ venue.latitude }}` part is converted into the value of `venue.latitude` *before* the javascript code is executed.

Comment: as soon as i use the double curly brace, the second curly brace on the right turned into red color as a sign that it cannot be used. (sublime text). Just to make sure, the javascript is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Try quoting that double curly brace "{{ venue.latitude }}"

Comment: is your script in same html file or writed on separate js file?

Comment: @CalebGoodman it just does not show anything on the map on the browser